# How to get All Credit card Details entered by Customer till now in Magento?

Tags: magento, credit-card

I have enabled "CC saved" method from Magento Admin Panel. I want list of all credit card details entered by Customer in drop down on checkout page. Can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution that you use "roll your own" for. There are transaction processing companies that have card wallet features that don't require you to save the credit card details yourself, which will be safer and more secure than this line of thinking.

The laws around storing credit card data are stringent, and from the sounds of it, this line of thinking will break several of them, exposing customers to a significant risk of credit card fraud.

I was going to find a solution for completeness, but couldn't bring myself to it.

Answer (score 0):

By chance I did exactly this for a client last week. My solution was to create a descendant of `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Payment_Collection` by supplying new classes, enabled with this config:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_eav</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_eav>
                <class>My_Module_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <payment><table>sales_flat_order_payment</table></payment>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_eav>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Payment.php`:

```
class My_Module_Model_Payment extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mymodule/payment'); // name of single resource model
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Resource/Payment.php`:

```
class My_Module_Model_Resource_Payment extends Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Payment
{} // no more is needed
```

`app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Resource/Payment/Collection.php`:

```
class My_Module_Model_Resource_Payment_Collection extends Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Payment_Collection
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mymodule/payment'); // model alias
    }

    public function addSavedFilter($customerId)
    {
        $this->join('sales/order', '`main_table`.`parent_id`=`sales/order`.`entity_id`', '');
        $this->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('cc_number_enc', array('neq'=>''))
             ->getSelect()->group(array('cc_exp_year', 'cc_exp_month', 'cc_owner', 'cc_last4', 'cc_type'));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I could then get a list like this:

```
$payments = Mage::getModel('mymodule/payment')->getCollection()->addSavedFilter($customer->getId());
```

**P.S.**
As Joseph points out storing credit card details has certain legal considerations. In this particular case my client was aware of all that and were prepared to take on the responsibility.

Comment: I have installed Onestepcheckout extension on my server so can you please tell me exact steps how to get an array of all credit cards of user? Please help

Comment: I don't know how that extension works but as it's a commercial one and you've already paid for and installed it the makers are obliged to a certain amount of support. They'll be able to give more information than I.

Comment: Yes. But I need to add this functionality(credit card) irrelevant of extension. Please tell me exact file(let it be core file also.I can change it.) where i need to write addSavedFilter() function and how to call that function in my phtml file.

Comment: The normal EAV approach was used just like the examples given in [the knowledge base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value). I have copied the salient parts of my previous work so you can see. There are no suprises here.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to consider is using the payment gateway to store credit cards *instead* of directly on the server and use their API to process order payments. A well known one that comes to mind is [Authorize.Net CIM (Customer Information Manager)](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/). This will offload many of the potential legality issues and is easier for your site to pass the PCI Compliance scan and rules. There are some payment method extensions for Magento that will help with this.